# Having problem with decimal points in MS Excel 2007

Tags: excel, decimal

I want to generate a graph with a large decimal number like -106.63633167743683 or 52.132235169410706. But whenever I'm entering the value in Excel sheet it is giving me value like -106.63633167743600 (as I have formatted cell with 15 decimal places). It is replacing the value of last two digits by 0.

Can anyone help regarding this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
106.63633167743600

          1    1
1--.-5----0----5
```

Excel numbers are stored as IEEE double values (See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113). That means the numbers can only have 15 *significant figures* of precision. To represent 106.63633167743683 one needs 17 significant figures, which is too much for Excel. Hence the last 2 digits become zero.

(Excel is not designed for high-precision arithmetic.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you suggest any tool as alternative?

Comment: @Eishita: Must you use a spreadsheet? Or are you willing to write a simple program?

Comment: I just need to draw a scatter graph for this large numbers. Any graph generator will work.

Comment: @Eishita: Try to find a programming language with a "BigFloat" library.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two numbers in your example both going to be on the scatter plot?  I can't imagine a computer monitor large enough to show them both to that precision anyway.  Wouldn't you need something that has 1.5*10^17 pixels in one direction?  My monitor, for example, is 1050 high.

Or if those are examples of numbers in different data sets, and you want to plot numbers like

-106.63633167743683

-106.63633167743692

where the differences are down in the 16th significant digit and beyond, you can simply plot

83

92

and get the same effect.